# How to disable formik form after submission of form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have created a formik form that stores values at the backend. I have set-reset button, initial values. Everything working fine. But I can't able to find a way to disable formik form after submission of the form i.e if the user fills the form after a click on submit button user is not able to click on the text field.

```
// @ts-ignore

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import { Typography, Button, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { MyInput } from './comman/MyInput';
import { Textarea } from './comman/Textarea';
import { Event } from '../Tracking/Event';

const contactSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required('Please Enter Your Name'),
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Please enter a valid email address')
    .required('Please enter an email address'),
  number: Yup.string()
    .min(10, 'Must be 10 digit.')
    .max(10, 'Must be 10 digit.'),
});
export default function ContactUs(props: any) {
  const [submitted,setSubmittde] = useState(false);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    msg: '',
  });
  const [selectedemail, setEmail] = useState({
    text: '',
  });
  const [comname, setComname] = useState({
    cName: '',
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${window.location.href}`);
    //const findemail = window.location.href;
    const findemail =
      'public/home';
    const email =
      findemail.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/) ||
      [];
    const finalemail = email[0].toString();
    const company = findemail.match(/(?<=%)\w+(?=&)/g) || [];
    const finalcompany = company.toString();

    setComname({ cName: finalcompany });

    setEmail({ text: finalemail });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src="public/logo"
        width="200"
        className="d-inline-block"
        alt="logo"
        style={{
          marginTop: '2em',
          marginBottom: '2em',
          float: 'right',
        }}
      />
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize
        initialValues={{
          name: '',
          email: selectedemail.text,
          number: '',
          companyname: comname.cName,
          message: '',
        }}
        validationSchema={contactSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
          const data = {
            name: values.name,
            email: values.email,
            number: values.number,
            companyname: values.companyname,
            message: values.message,
            formtype: 'Email Marketing Contactus',
          };
          const request = new Request(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_PRODUCTION_EMAILCONTACTUS_API}`,
            {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              }),
              body: JSON.stringify(data),
            },
          );

          fetch(request)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
              if (
                data.message ===
                'We have received your message and will get in touch shortly. Thanks!'
              ) {
                setState({
                  msg: data.message,
                });
              } else {
                console.log('error');
              }
            });
          resetForm();
        }}
      >
        {({ errors, touched }) => (
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography
                variant="body1"
                style={{
                  marginTop: '1em',
                  fontFamily: 'roboto',
                  fontSize: '1.3rem',
                  color: '#2F4858',
                }}
              >
                To know more please submit your information, and one of our
                expert advisors will get in touch within 24 hours!{' '}
              </Typography>
              <br />

              <Form>
                <Typography
                  variant="h6"
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: 'roboto',
                    color: '#2F4858',
                    marginTop: '0.5em',
                  }}
                >
                  Full Name
                </Typography>
                <Field
                  id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  component={MyInput}
                />
                <br />
                {errors.name && touched.name ? (
                  <div className="text-danger" style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                    {errors.name}
                  </div>
                ) : null}
                <Typography
                  variant="h6"
                  style={{ fontFamily: 'roboto', marginTop: '1em' }}
                >
                  Email
                </Typography>
                <Field
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  values={props.text}
                  style={{ color: 'white' }}
                  component={MyInput}
                />{' '}
                <br />
                {errors.email && touched.email ? (
                  <div className="text-danger" style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                    {errors.email}
                  </div>
                ) : null}
                <Typography
                  variant="h6"
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: 'roboto',
                    color: '#2F4858',
                    marginTop: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  Mobile Number (Optional)
                </Typography>
                <Field
                  name="number"
                  placeholder="Contact Number"
                  component={MyInput}
                  // label="Contact Number"
                />
                <br />
                {errors.number && touched.number ? (
                  <div className="text-danger" style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                    {errors.number}
                  </div>
                ) : null}
                <Typography
                  variant="h6"
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: 'roboto',
                    color: '#2F4858',
                    marginTop: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  Company Name (Optional)
                </Typography>
                <Field
                  name="companyname"
                  placeholder="Company Name"
                  // label="Contact Number"
                  component={MyInput}
                />
                <br />
                <Typography
                  variant="h6"
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: 'roboto',
                    color: '#2F4858',
                    marginTop: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  How can we help? (Optional)
                </Typography>
                <Field
                  id="outlined-multiline-static"
                  name="message"
                  placeholder="Your question about our services"
                  label="How can we help?"
                  component={Textarea}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={() =>
                    Event(
                      'Contact from',
                      'Client submitted ',
                      'domain',
                    )
                  }
                  
                  style={{
                    background: '#F79924',
                    color: 'white',
                    fontFamily: 'roboto',
                    fontSize: '1rem',
                  }}
                >
                  Submit{' '}
                </Button>
                <br />
                {state.msg && (
                  <Typography
                    variant="h6"
                    style={{
                      color: '#4BB543',
                      fontFamily: 'roboto-medium',
                      marginTop: '1em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {' '}
                    {state.msg}{' '}
                  </Typography>
                )}
              </Form>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[![Formik form][1]][1]

I don't know how to disable formik form. Please help?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQXBV.png

Comment: use a state `submited` and set it to `true` when the form submits, then for each field, add `disabled={submited}`,

Comment: @sairaj I have edited my question with code. Please suggest to me where to add code as you suggested??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be simply done using the `disabled` attribute and your existing value `isSubmitted`.

Pass a prop `disabled` into your custom input:

```
<Field
  type="email"
  name="email"
  placeholder="Email"
  values={props.text}
  style={{ color: 'white' }}
  component={MyInput}
  disabled={isSubmitted}
/>
```

And apply it in the custom input using the `...props` spread:

```
const MyInput = ({
  field,
  label,
  name,
  id,
  value,
  ...props
}) => (
  <div>
    <label htmlFor="id">{label} </label>
    <input id={id} type="text" {...field} {...props} />
  </div>
);
```

And make sure you set `isSubmitted` somewhere in the onSubmit function

```
fetch(request)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        if (
        data.message ===
        'We have received your message and will get in touch shortly. Thanks!'
        ) {
        setState({
            msg: data.message,
        });
        setIsSubmitted(true);
        } else {
        console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-html-input-fields-and-custom-validation-rules-forked-e2vpl?file=/src/Form/Form.jsx:105-329) of a simple form that disables inputs/button after submission.